# allocate a 3d array that contains strings

Tags: c, matrix, tensor

I wrote a 'class' that can store strings (2d array/matrix). This works fine, but now I need a way to store that matrix. So I need to calloc the 3tensor but i am not sure how to do it beyond the matrice allocation. 
My 2d array looks like this: \

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h> /* uints */
#include <string.h> /* char */

/* struct that holds data about the matrix, so it can be resized when needed */

struct Arr {

    char** cArr;

    unsigned int currentSize, maxSize;

};

/* initial allocation function that is used when a array needs te be calloced at first */

uint8_t initialAlloc(struct Arr* arr);

/* reallocate the array to a hardcoded size */

uint8_t reallocArr(struct Arr* arr);

/* add an element to the array in arr */

void addToArr(struct Arr* arr, char* element);
```

```
#include "arr.h"

uint8_t initialAlloc(struct Arr* arr) {

    arr->currentSize = 0;

    arr->maxSize = 2;

    arr->cArr = calloc(2, sizeof(char*));

    if (!arr->cArr) {
    
        return 0;

    }

    for (uint8_t x = 0; x < arr->maxSize; ++x) {

        arr->cArr[x] = calloc(600, sizeof(char));

        if (!arr->cArr[x]) {

            return 0;
        
        }

    }

    return 1;

}

void addToArr(struct Arr* arr, char* element) {

    if (arr->currentSize == arr->maxSize) {

        if (!reallocArr(arr)) {

            /* if the memory allocation fails something is bad wrong */

            exit(1);

        }

    }
    
    strncpy(arr->cArr[arr->currentSize], element, strlen(element));

    ++arr->currentSize;

}

uint8_t reallocArr(struct Arr* arr) {

    uint16_t resizeTo = arr->maxSize * 2;

    arr->cArr = realloc(arr->cArr, resizeTo * sizeof(char*));

    if (!arr->cArr) {

        return 0;

    }


    for (uint16_t x = arr->currentSize; x < resizeTo; ++x) {

        arr->cArr[x] = calloc(600, sizeof(char));

        if (!arr->cArr[x]) {

            return 0;

        }
    }

    arr->maxSize = arr->maxSize * 2;

    return 1;

}
```

I want to use the `Arr` struct inside the 3tensor.

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h> /* basic functions */
#include <stdint.h> /* uint */

/* user includes */

#include "characterArr.h" 

/* user includes */


struct Tensor {

    char*** mArr;

    unsigned int currentSize, maxSize;

};

uint8_t initialAllocTensor(struct Tensor* tensor);

uint8_t reallocTensor(struct Tensor* tensor);

void addToTensor(struct Tensor* tensor, struct Arr* arr);
```

```
/* user includes */

#include "tensor.h"

/* user includes */


/* initial allocation function that is used when a array needs te be calloced at first */

uint8_t initialAllocTensor(struct Tensor* tensor) {

    tensor->currentSize = 0;

    tensor->maxSize = 2;

    tensor->mArr = calloc(2, sizeof(struct *Arr));

    if (!tensor->mArr) {
    
        return 0;

    }

    for (uint8_t x = 0; x < arr->maxSize; ++x) {

        arr->cArr[x] = calloc(600, sizeof(char));

        if (!arr->cArr[x]) {

            return 0;
        
        }

    }

    return 1;

}
```

After I allocate the memory that will contain the pointers to the `Arr` struct, I get lost. The reason is, I need the information in the `Arr` struct for later use, so why would I recopy all the data from the `Arr` struct that i already have into the newly created 3Tensor. `Could I just store a pointer to the` Arr `struct in the Tensor then be done?` `If i do this, would I be able to access the` Arr `struct just fine?` Since I malloced this, I wouldn't need to worry about the memory getting taken when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Side note: it is not a good idea to put blank lines in between each line. It makes the
code much less readable with limited view of lines.

Comment: would've thought the opposite, it is harder to read here honestly but not in sublime which is the editor i am using

Comment: `tensor->mArr = calloc(2, sizeof(struct *Arr));` is suspicious.

Comment: @CoN Use blank lines to separate parts of the code that don't obviously belong directly together. For example a `calloc` call and the following mandatory check vs NULL belong together so no need for an empty line there.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica why is that? Should i get the size from the variable not the declaration? So if i had a variable named struct Arr arr; i would do sizeof(&arr); ?

Comment: @CoN `tensor->mArr` is a `char ***`.  Unclear why a size of `sizeof(struct *Arr)` is being allocated.

Comment: oh i see that, what would i malloc instead of that though?

Comment: i should malloc the struct Arr after the first malloc to the 3tensor is done